# What exaclty does the Message Format ".NetBinary" for ServiceEndpoint-Registration?

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online, azure-queues

I've tried to get answers by googling it but I can't find appropriate information about this.

What exactly means ".NetBinary" when a ServiceEndpoint is registered by the PluginRegistration-Tool for sending for example the PluginExecutionContext to a azure queue?

Actually we use JSON but I would like to know more about this particular message format.

Can pls somebody provide some clarification?